# Error occurred when using thread_local to maintain a concurrent memory buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

In the following code, I want to create a memory buffer that allows multiple threads to read/write it concurrently. At a time, all threads will read this buffer in parallel, and later they will write to the buffer in parallel. But there will be no read/write operation at the same time.

To do this, I use a `vector` of `shared_ptr<vector<uint64_t>>`. When a new thread arrives, it will be allocated with a new `vector<uint64_t>` and only write to it. Two threads will not write to the same vector.

I use thread_local to track the vector index and offset the current thread will write to. When I need to add a new buffer to the `memory_` variable, I use a mutex to protect it.

```
class TestBuffer {
public:
    thread_local static uint32_t index_;
    thread_local static uint32_t offset_;
    thread_local static bool ready_;

    vector<shared_ptr<vector<uint64_t>>> memory_;
    mutex lock_;

    void init() {
        if (!ready_) {
            new_slab();
            ready_ = true;
        }
    }

    void new_slab() {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> lock(lock_);
        index_ = memory_.size();
        memory_.push_back(make_shared<vector<uint64_t>>(1000));
        offset_ = 0;
    }

    void put(uint64_t value) {
        init();
        if (offset_ == 1000) {
            new_slab();
        }
        if(memory_[index_] == nullptr) {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        }
        *(memory_[index_]->data() + offset_) = value;
        offset_++;
    }
};

thread_local uint32_t TestBuffer::index_ = 0;
thread_local uint32_t TestBuffer::offset_ = 0;
thread_local bool TestBuffer::ready_ = false;

int main() {
    TestBuffer buffer;
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        thread t = thread([&buffer, i]() {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
                buffer.put(i * 10000 + j);
            }
        });
        threads.emplace_back(move(t));
    }
    for (auto &t: threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The code does not behave as expected, and reports error is in the `put` function. The root cause is that `memory_[index_]` sometimes return `nullptr`. However, I do not understand why this is possible as I think I have set the values properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not normal to see this much `thread_local` in your code. Don't use global variables like this, if it's thread local, scope it within the thread's function. I'm not sure this strategy is safe, nor recommended. If you want a memory pool shared between threads that's achievable, but should not require any `thread_local` overhead.

Comment: Is the goal here to have some kind of container you can write to in parallel and then read back once all the data has been accumulated? If so, why all this fuss instead of the threads adding vectors to a target `queue` when they're full/ready? The C++ pattern would be some kind of stream-style object where you could do `Buffer b ` then `b << value` then `b.close()`.

Comment: Your put() method will only expand the vector once. What happens when offset_ reaches 2000, etc?

Comment: @JohnSheridan It's fine, `new_slab` resets `offset_` to zero.

Comment: @PaulSanders indeed it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition in `put` caused by `new_slab()`.  When `new_slab` calls `memory_.push_back()` the `_memory` vector may need to resize itself, and if another thread is executing `put` while the resize is in progress, `memory_[index_]` might access stale data.

One solution is to protect the `_memory` vector by locking the mutex:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<mutex> lock(lock_);

    if(memory_[index_] == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    *(memory_[index_]->data() + offset_) = value;
}
```

Another is to reserve the space you need in the `memory_` vector ahead of time.